# open a ctrl-a delimited file in excel

Tags: excel, hive, delimiter

I have a file that was delimited in Hive with a ctrl-a delimiter ('001' I believe?)  I need to open it in excel but I don't know to specify that delimiter in the 'text to columns' tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows OS download  **sed** from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) or [here](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) and run your input file through it like that:

```
sed 's/yourdelimiter/,/g' < input > output.csv
```

This will give you a comma separated file that excel will correctly parse.
Your delimiter is most probably `\001`

See a [sed tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) for more info.